# Publish a paper of my master thesis

Tags: publications, thesis

I finished my master thesis in a high ranking university. The thesis idea is simple and not novel, however the results are higher that the state of art.
My supervisor is one of the top in the field. When I asked him to try to publish a paper of my work, he refused and he said the work should be "novel".
I am pretty sure that he is addressing TOP conferences and journals only. But, what I think is publish the paper in middle-tier conference or even workshop, so I can boost my profile.
Is it possible to submit it without adding his name?

Any ideas or advices?

Answer (score 3):

If your supervisor is one of the top people in the field and doesn't think the work merits publication, I would heed his advice. Furthermore, publishing work without his consent that he has helped you with (even if you don't include his name) is a very bad idea. Why don't you talk to your supervisor again and ask him his opinion on publishing in a lower-tier journal?

Comment: I am pretty sure that my work could be accepted in a middle-tier conference or a workshop. But I believe he doesn't like to target non-high (top) places. Furthermore, the work is mainly done by me and my advisor (PhD student). Definitely, everything is decided by the professor (supervisor).